# Interactive matplotlib plot: Define and plot a polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a grid of hexagons using `matplotlib.patches` library. The figure that is shown by my program is interactive: It allows for picking a hexagon with the left mouse button, which results in filling the hexagon black. This way, I am marking the circumference of a polygon:

[image: hexagons]

Now, I want to connect the filled hexagons, such that I can see the circumference of the polygon. I want the polygon to be drawn upon pressing a key. Here is my idea:

```
    def draw_circumference(event):
        if event.key == 'd':
            print(circumference)
            plt.Polygon(circumference, fill=False, edgecolor='k')
            #fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", draw_circumference)
```

The variable `circumference` contains the (x,y) coordinates of the respective centers of the marked hexagons as a list of tuples: `[(x1,y1), x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn)]`. I have commented the `fig.canvas.draw()` because I think it should work without this line. But so far it does not work, neither with, nor without `fig.canvas.draw()`.

The function gets called, however. I know this as the print-statement is executed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to debug without the full code, but usually you have to add a patch artist such as a polygon explicitly to the axis. Also, you probably do need the redraw call as the contents of the axis have changed.

```
p = plt.Polygon(circumference, ...)
ax.add_patch(p) # or ax.add_artist(p)
fig.canvas.draw()
```